# issue with bash comparison operator between two strings

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

Hi I've been ripping my hair out trying to perform a comparison operator between a `string` and another `string` in bash, but cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

I have the following in a `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
- firstchar=$(head -c 1 file.json)
- echo $firstchar   #returns:  {
- if [[ $firstchar == "[" ]]
- then
- echo "yay"
else
- echo "an error occurred"
- fi
```

On line 3 I'm simplying trying to compare the value of `$firstchar` to see if it matches literally `[` . I've tried printing out `$firstchar` and it prints `{` but then its hitting this `if` condition.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: What output do you expect from your script?

Comment: `yay` is the happy path. Not sure if that `if [[ $firstchar == "[" ]]` is right

Comment: Are you sure your shell is `bash`? `and it prints {` please show the output of `hexdump -C <<<"$firstchar"`. Please add `set -x` to the script and show the output.

Comment: If your variable contains a curly bracket ("{"), and you're comparing it to a *square* bracket ("["), it should not match. So it looks like it's working as I'd expect it to.

Comment: well no @GordonDavisson - `file.json` has a `{`in it, but the logic isnt printing `an error occurred`

Comment: @Jshee Then what *does* it do, and how does this differ from what you expected it to do? Please include this information in your question; don't make us guess about what's going wrong!

Comment: @Jshee : May I ask why each line in your posting has a preceeding `-`, with the sole exception of the `else` line?

Comment: @user1934428 - this is `gitlab-ci` syntax

Comment: @Jshee : I see. And what does the **missing** dash in front of the `else` indicate then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You didn't do anything wrong. Your program is correct and delivers the correct result for the input you specified.